# Will JavaScript evaluate a property's value if it's not part of an assignment statement?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, variables, evaluation

I've come across a fairly obscure problem having to do with measuring a document's height before the styling has been applied by the browser. More information here:

- http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing
- http://ajaxian.com/archives/safari-3-onload-firing-and-bad-timing

In Dave Hyatt's comment from June 27, he advises simply checking the `document.body.offsetLeft` property to force Safari to do a reflow.

Can I simply use the following statement:

```
document.body.offsetLeft;
```

or do I need to assign it to a variable, e.g.:

```
var force_layout = document.body.offsetLeft;
```

in order for browsers to calculate that value?

I think this comes down to a more fundamental question - that is, without being part of an assignment statement, will JavaScript still evaluate a property's value? Does this depend on whether a particular browser's JavaScript engine optimizes the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement will still be evaluated.

```
     Property Accessors
            |    |
            v    v
    document.body.offsetLeft;
      ^
      |- Identifier Reference
```

In the above statement, you can see that `document` is a [Identifier Reference](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.2), which is a [Primary Expression](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1).

Then the property accessor operator is used (`.`) too lookup the `body` property and then the `offsetLeft` property.

You are not doing an `AssignmentExpression` but the statement will be evaluated because the Identifier Reference is resolved, and the properties are looked up.

Also, host objects, can implement *accessor properties* that can have a logic `get` and `set` methods, not just simple *value properties*.

In ECMAScript 3, we didn't had the power of creating *accessor properties*, only the host objects could implement them, but the 5th Edition of the standard allows us to do it.

For example to illustrate:

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop', { // ECMAScript 5 method
  get: function () {
    alert('getter');
  }
});
```

<sub>**Note:** The above illustrative example works on IE9 Pre, Firefox 3.7alpha, Chrome 5, and WebKit nightly builds.</sub>

Then a simple expression as your example, makes the getter to invoke:

```
obj.prop; // alerts "getter"
```

Comment: Great explanation! That makes sense. I had a hunch that that's what was happening, but I couldn't articulate it as such. Thanks so much, CMS!